# Is there a way to specify a global options chunk function in Rmarkdown so that only some of the graphs will show/not show by toggling the command?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I currently have a subset of figures in Rmarkdown but would like to hide or display them by specifying `echo = F` or `echo = T` for those only. It is tedious to go through each of the figures I want to hide or display and change the echo option. Is there a global way of toggling or making certain figures show? In other words, is there a way to perhaps do:

````
```{r, echo.func}
include.graphics("this/plot/shows.jpg")
```
````

and be able to somehow control `echo.func` to be equal to `echo = F` or `echo = T` in the beginning? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `echo=` can be a full expression, so you can define *classes* or *individual* blocks. Something like this:

````
---
title: echo test
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, echo = FALSE, include = FALSE}
echolist <- c("plots", "table2")
```

```{r table1, echo = any(c("tables", "table1") %in% echolist)}
# mtcars[1:3,]
```

```{r plot1, echo = any(c("plots", "plot1") %in% echolist)}
# plot(1)
```

```{r table2, echo = any(c("tables", "table2") %in% echolist)}
# mtcars[5:10,]
```

```{r plot2, echo = any(c("plots", "plot2") %in% echolist)}
# plot(2)
```
````

[image: rmarkdown output]

From this, I think it'd be feasible to write a function that you pass the block name (e.g., `{r blockname, echo=checkecho("blockname")}`), and internally it does something that perhaps checks literal titles, patterns, groups, etc.

---

Suggestion for functionizing it:

````
---
title: echo test
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, echo = FALSE, include = FALSE}
.checkecho <- function(nm) {
  any(c(nm, gsub("\\d+$", "s", nm)) %in% c("plots", "table2"))
}
```

```{r table1, echo = .checkecho("table1")}
# mtcars[1:3,]
```

```{r plot1, echo = .checkecho("plot1")}
# plot(1)
```

```{r table2, echo = .checkecho("plot2")}
# mtcars[5:10,]
```

```{r plot2, echo = .checkecho("table2")}
# plot(2)
```
````

The biggest take-away from this is for you to come up with a naming standard that will facilitate your job. In this example:

- everything starts with a simple description of expected output and ends with a number (which does not need to be incrementing *shrug*);
- you can control individual echo-ing by specifying specific blocks or by removing the number and adding an "s"

You can easily turn this into a negation policy instead, where you turn off specific elements ... the possibilities are numerous and probably why there is not already a function in `rmarkdown` or `knitr` that facilitates this.

(If you're curious ... I chose to start the function name with a dot so that, if for some reason you include the output from `ls()` in your report, the function will not be included. To see it, you'd need to do `ls(all.names=TRUE)`. *shrug*)

Comment: This is the most ingenious solution I've seen. Thank you. For writing such as function as `checkecho()`, how can I go about defining it? Is this something RMarkdown allows me to do at the beginning?

Comment: Sure, I'd place it within something like my `setup` block. I don't think it needs to be displayed in the report (as opposed to needing `library(...)` to be visible, perhaps), so `echo=F,include=F` seems reasonable for that block.

Comment: See my edit, I think it gives a good example of where you might want to start your "naming convention".

Comment: Thanks very much, this is great. Much appreciate your time and help.