# Selectively knitting R notebook

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I would like to make long, well documented R-studio notebooks to completely document analyses, but then be able to knit either the full notebook or an abbreviated version for reports for different audiences. The long version for scientists and a short version as an executive summary.

I know about not running individual chunks, but is there a way to specify chunks together with sections of supporting text to be knit or not, and then somehow turn on or off the selective knitting?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705662/how-to-request-an-early-exit-when-knitting-an-rmd-document) shows how to use knit_exit() to exit knitting early, but I am looking for a way to go in and out multiple times through a document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57436988 ... please test it and report back, as I think it'll address your needs.

Comment: You can write a script and pass your notebook to `rmarkdown::render` with different `params` that contain chunks to knit. Read `?rmarkdown::render`

Comment: These are all helpful, but I don't think any of these suggestions allow you to turn off the knitting of the text outside of the R chunks? That is specifically what I am interested in. For example, I might have A discussion of a mathematical formula (in LaTeX) that precedes the R code chunk, and sometimes I might want to hide the whole thing, math discussion plus code chunk. If I am wrong let me know and I will look into those sources more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

````
---
title: study sample
output: pdf_document
---

```{r beginning, echo = FALSE, include = FALSE}
echoaudience <- c("scientific", "executive")
```

```{r data1, echo = any(c("scientific","tested") %in% echoaudience)}
# a detailed report
```

```{r data2, echo = any(c("executive","brief") %in% echoaudience)}
# a brief summary
```

```{r data3, echo = any(c("myleftover","brief") %in% echoaudience)}
# some data only in my interest
```
````

It will return only the code you want to show, in this case data1 and data2. You can control the outputs.

````
```r
# a quite detailed info
```

```r
# a brief summary
```
````

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Alexis